# "Google Sheet" ,Compare two columns & return value

Tags: sql, google-sheets, vlookup, gs-vlookup

I want to do some function like sql joint table.
But I really dont know if google sheet can do it.

I want to compare two columns and return the cost, how can I perform it?

```
ColA ColB                                  ColG ColH

Type Cost                                  Type Cost
A    100                                   B
B    200                                   E
C    300                                   D
D    400                                   A
E    500                                   C
```

I want colH would show colB data when comparing colG to colA,
is there any function in google sheet that can do it?
It's just like the joint table function sql table.

Thanks

Comment: Do not change perfectly useful textual information into a picture of text. Helping you is easier if the needed information is available in a shape which can be copied easily, searched, edited, ...

Comment: Have you tried the Conditional formatting?  see this https://zapier.com/blog/conditional-formatting-google-sheets/

Comment: I tried =lookup & =IF but it won't show the exact result i want,

Comment: Can you share the formula that you were using? (I think it can be done with either IF or with the Conditional Formatting)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Next time, you may try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this makes it easier to give you some help ;)

Comment: It's simple, =lookup(M3,J:J,K:K) , I know it's kind of simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vertical Lookup function `VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) is what you want to solve this problem.

```
VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
```

Pass the following parameters:

- `search_key` is the value to search in the costs array, column G in you case.
- `range` is the costs array
- `index` is the column to return in the costs array, the second one
- `is_sorted` should be set to `TRUE`, as you do not want incorrect costs to be returned, if the value in column G does not exist in the costs array.

Hence, the formula to use in H2 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,A1:B6,2,false)
```

Then, in order to allow you to use the same formula in all cells inside the column H, you need you make sure that it is always `A1:B6` which is looked up as the costs array. If you copy paste the formula above from H2 to H3, it will adapt it and move the array one line below (A2:B7), which is not what you want. To solve this, you should use the dollar sign to lock the costs array range. [This article](https://support.knewton.com/faq-library/using-statistical-software-with-knewton/cell-references-and-using-the-dollar-sign) explains how it works.

The formula then becomes the one below, and you can copy/paste it inside the whole column H:

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,$A$1:$B$6,2,false)
```

Demo sheet with the solution in place: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzvCmgTi1DgA5Dbwb_iwKYc5RW_9uwFs2sVR0PbN7Ic/edit?usp=sharing